# Visibility Analysis Plugin (QGIS 3.18.3) Returning multiple errors

Tags: qgis-3, error, viewshed, array

I am trying to run a viewshed analysis in QGIS 3.18.3 using the Visibility Analysis plugin. I have followed the steps entirely in both of these videos:
https://youtu.be/pt1gFXON7W4
https://youtu.be/fGKgvg0QoXA

but it continued to throw an error. Both the "viewpoint" and the DEM are in UTM coordinates. Any ideas on how to fix this? I ran the same process in ArcGIS Pro and it worked fine.

Here is the error log that I get when I try and run the analysis:

```
QGIS code revision: 735cc85be9
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.1.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Viewshed' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ANALYSIS_TYPE' : 0, 'DEM' : 'C:/Users/Arda/Documents/Summer 2021/Viewshed_Paper/New folder/clip_aster.tif', 'OBSERVER_POINTS' : 'C:/Users/Arda/Documents/Summer 2021/Viewshed_Paper/New folder/point_loc_shp.shp', 'OPERATOR' : 0, 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'REFRACTION' : 0.13, 'USE_CURVATURE' : False }

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Arda/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\algorithms\viewshed_raster.py", line 251, in processAlgorithm
refraction = refraction )
File "C:/Users/Arda/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\algorithms\modules\Raster.py", line 151, in set_master_window
self.window = np.zeros((full_size, full_size))
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 9.21 PiB for an array with shape (35998455, 35998455) and data type float64

Execution failed after 0.07 seconds
```

Comment: Clear: you have memory errors. 9.21 PiB more or less 9210000GiB (or 9210 TiB)... What extent your input files are covering? And what is their files size? Clearly, what you are trying to do is to run the algorithm in conditions where nearly no computers with current best specs can run it.

Comment: @ThomasG77 Well that is alarming! The DEM I am using is a single ASTER DEM that is clipped to about 5km x 5km. I tried it with a separate DEM as well so I will have to try out some new data to see if that solves the 10 petabyte problem. Thank you for your quick response!